# How to print EMPTY result in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I using phpMyAdmin 4.4.14 in Win7+Chrome and MySQL 5.6 in Linux.

For example, when I issue this SQL:

select * from txn_table where txn_date >= '2016-02-15'

If this SQL return 3 rows, I can print it.

I can click the `Print View` to generate a clean HTML in a new tab-sheet in Chrome with a `Print` button at the bottom.  The HTML print out will have Generation Time and Database information, etc.  I can submit the print out to my manager for reporting purpose.

However, if the SQL return 0 rows, I cannot print.  There is no `Print View` in the screen to generate a clean HTML.  I have nothing to submit to my manager.  If I screen dump, there is no date time information.  I have to manually write down the date time.

Is there any parameter setting to solve this problem so that I can print a 0-row result ?

Cheers,
Alvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that wasn't envisioned when the new print view was created. A workaround, of course, is to simply use your browser's "Print" functionality to print the page -- which has gotten some attention in recent versions, so at least now your output can look like this:

[image: New style]

instead of this:

[image: Old style]

So perhaps upgrading would be sufficient for you. You're also welcome to add this to the issue tracker at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/ where it can be logged as a feature request.